# Run Batch Command on Iterative Text Files

Tags: windows, batch-file, iteration

I have a set of text files (log0.txt, log1.txt, etc) which I want to convert to a different format. However, the last line of each file is incomplete, so I want to write a Batch command which will delete the last line of each file.

The general command I got to work looks like this:

```
@echo off 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

rem Count the lines in file 
set /a count=-1 
for /F %%a in (log0.txt) DO set /a count=!count!+1 

rem Create empty temp file 
copy /y NUL temp.txt >NUL 

rem Copy all but last line 
for /F %%a in (log0.txt) DO ( 
IF /I !count! GTR 0 ( 
echo %%a >>temp.txt 
set /a count=!count!-1 
) 
) 

rem overwrite original file, delete temp file 
copy /y temp.txt log0.txt >NUL 
del temp.txt 

rem This for testing 
type log0.txt
```

Instead of having to copy and paste this for each text file, is there a way for the Batch command to operate on all of my text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclusion of the last line may be achieved in a simpler way. I modified your code and added the processing of all text files.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all text files
for %%f in (*.txt) do (

   echo Processing: %%f

   rem Copy all but last line in temp.txt file
   set "line="
   (for /F %%a in (%%f) do (
      if defined line echo !line!
      set "line=%%a"
   )) > temp.txt

   rem Overwrite original file
   move /Y temp.txt %%f >NUL 

   rem This for testing 
   type %%f

)
```

Comment: The idea in your loop is really nice

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild your code to a function.

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
  call :removeLastLine "%%~F"
)
exit /b

:removeLastLine
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set "filename=%~1"
echo Processing '!filename!'

rem Count the lines in file 
set /a count=-1 
for /F %%a in (!filename!) DO set /a count+=1

rem Copy all but last line 
(
  for /F %%a in (!filename!) DO ( 
    IF /I !count! GTR 0 ( 
      echo(%%a
    set /a count=!count!-1 
    ) 
  )
) > temp.txt 

rem overwrite original file, delete temp file 
copy /y temp.txt !filename! >NUL 
del temp.txt 

rem This for testing 
type !filename!
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: I tried copy all that (both the function and the call line) into a batch file and running it - but it didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: The function must be after the for loop, I will edit edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Using powershell script may be faster than your method.  Put the following script into a file called allbutlast.ps1:

```
$content = Get-Content $args[0]
$lines = $content | Measure-Object
$content | select -First ($lines.count-1)
```

Then call this from you batch file with:

```
powershell -file allbutlast.ps1 log0.txt>temp.txt
copy /y temp.txt log0.txt >NUL
del temp.txt
```